# MongoDB upgrade cannot be done in hours

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

Background: Every 2 months, the MongoDB server encounters an exception due to an excessive number of file handles that cannot be released, causing slow access and requiring a restart. The `close_idle_time` in the MongoDB 3.6 version was investigated to be 100,000, which takes about 28 hours to release the file handles. This parameter was adjusted to 600, 10 minutes in version 4.4. Therefore, upgrading the MongoDB version is attempted to avoid the problem of the MongoDB service exception caused by the failure to release the file handles.

The data in the chart represents the number of open file handles, and the trough represents the weekend.

[image]

```
Hardware: 3 physical servers with 56 cores and 256 GB RAM, using SSD RAID10 with 4x1.92T disks for MongoDB data partition.

MongoDB: MongoDB cluster deployed in a 3-node master-slave ReplicaSet with version 3.6.20.

Data: One MongoDB instance has 2 databases:

DB1 with 90,000 collections, taking up 460 GB of disk space, including 91,540 collection wt files and 183,081 index wt files.
DB2 with 819,500 collections, taking up 170 GB of disk space, including 835,215 collection wt files and 1,670,452 index wt files.
```

**Solution 1:** Upgrading the version to solve the problem of excessive file handles not being released in MongoDB, as discovered in technical articles related to file handle numbers.

**Result of Solution 1:** The upgrade failed due to the large number of data files, and upgrading the data files for a single instance takes too long. The business cannot accept it.

**Solution 2:** Deleting 50% of historical data before upgrading.

**Problem with Solution 2:** After deleting the data, no disk space was released. It was found that MongoDB marks the data as deleted but does not actually release the disk space. Attempting to use "compact" to release disk space resulted in the need for more disk space and memory to complete the operation. In addition, the compact operation is extremely slow, with a large difference between the actual and expected operation time. Therefore, this solution is currently deemed not feasible.

Comment: In a 3-member replica set, it should be possible to upgrade without any downtime, see [Upgrade a Replica Set to 4.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-replica-set/) Then you may review your database design, almost one million collections seems to be very much and most likely indicates a poor data design. Do you use a collection for each single document?

Comment: Yes, the database design is not good :(, each collection represent a user. We will change it after the upgrade.